# Getting the optimal resolution in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, resolution, monitor

Is there any way of getting the monitors optimal resolution in vb?

Comment: Define "optimal". That's kinda subjective

Comment: @dario_ramos I think he means "recommended" which is shown in windows

Comment: The MSDN says that recommended resolutions are listed. Where do you see "the" recommended one? If this is a Windows 7 thing, touché; I still haven't made the 7 voyage

Comment: The **optimal** resolution is the screen resolution your monitor is designed for.  A 1080p LCD screen is designed for 1920x1080.  It can display lower resolutions, but they come out distorted and chunky.  1920x1080 is **optimal** in this case.

Comment: @dario_ramos Optimal is an Adjective: Best or most favorable; optimum.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food Yes that is correct, that is what I want to know. If the user is using the optimal resolution. If there is an API or any other function to actually know if a user is using the optimal resolution of the screen. Windows give a notification when you aren't using optimal resolution. Try using a lower resolution and restarting the computer. After logging back on it may give a notification about the optimal resolution. Thanks.

Comment: I think the term the OP is referring to is the [Native resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_resolution) - note that this is not applicable for CRT monitors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Optimal Resolution Based on Advices

If you want the optimal resolution for a CRT then you can follow [Microsoft's advice](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/Getting-the-best-display-on-your-monitor#section_3) (because there is no native resolution for a CRT):

> For a CRT monitor, it's important to change the screen resolution to
>   the highest resolution available that provides 32-bit color and at
>   least a 72-Hertz refresh rate.

If you want the optimal resolution for a LCD monitor then you have to use its *native resolution*.  Usually it's the highest resolution available for the monitor.

#### Ways of Getting Optimal Resolution

You can get resolution information from various sources:

1. Windows API (with User32.dll)
2. DirectX (using the SDK)
3. Windows Management Instrumentation (a.k.a. WMI)

#### Optimal Resolution Based on VB Code

I'll use some WMI to query the resolution informations.  We can use the Win32_VideoSettings class which gives us available resolutions by video controller but I had some funny/sad/empty results with it.  For this one, I'm using the [CIM_VideoControllerResolution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa388669%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) class directly to get the maximum resolution:

```
Imports System.Management
'...
    Public Function GetMaximumResolution() As ManagementObject

            Dim className As String = "CIM_VideoControllerResolution"
            Dim computerName As String = "."

            Dim managementPath As New ManagementPath("\\" & computerName & "\root\cimv2:" & className)
            Dim scope As New ManagementScope(managementPath)

            Dim videoCtrlrRes As ManagementObjectCollection
            Using searcher As ManagementObjectSearcher = New ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from " & className)
                searcher.Scope = scope
                videoCtrlrRes = searcher.Get()
            End Using

            Dim videoCtrlrResList As New List(Of ManagementObject)

            For Each videoCtrlResItem In videoCtrlrRes
                'Console.WriteLine(videoCtrlResItem("Description"))
                videoCtrlrResList.Add(videoCtrlResItem)
            Next

            Dim maximumResolution As ManagementObject = videoCtrlrResList.
                OrderBy(Function(vidSetting) vidSetting("HorizontalResolution")).
                ThenBy(Function(vidSetting) vidSetting("VerticalResolution")).
                ThenBy(Function(vidSetting) vidSetting("NumberOfColors")).
                LastOrDefault()
            'Console.WriteLine(maximumResolution("Description"))

            Return maximumResolution
        End Function
```

Note: if you want to get the resfresh rate, you can get it with the 'RefreshRate' property (ex. vidSetting("RefreshRate") )

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. If I could vote up more I would keep voting. Thanks so much. =]