# Get optimal screen resolution on Windows using .NET

Tags: .net, windows, screen

On Windows 7 the optimal screen resolution settings are recognized in the system control, but how can I get this information with an .NET application?

Here is a screenshot of the window I mean:[image: screen resolution in Windows 7]

I have already checked this question: [Getting the optimal resolution in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668275/getting-the-optimal-resolution-in-visual-studio-2010)
However this solution can only be used to get the highest possible resolution, which is not the recommenced in some cases.

Comment: Same idea, but use Win32_DesktopMonitor to get the properties of the monitor.

Comment: I tried the properties `ScreenWidth` and `ScreenHeight`, but this is only the current resolution of the monitor. Have I missed something?